# Spark: importing text file in UTF-8 encoding

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to process a file which contains a lot of special characters such as German umlauts(ä,ü,o) etc. as follows :

`sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "\r\n\r\n")` `sc.textFile("/file/path/samele_file.txt")`

But upon reading the contents, these special characters are not recognized.

I think the default encoding is not in UTF-8 or similar formats. I would like to know if there is a way to set encoding on this textFile method such as:

```
sc.textFile("/file/path/samele_file.txt",mode="utf-8")`
```

Answer (score 2):

No, if you read a non UTF-8 format file in UTF-8 mode, non-ascii characters will not be decoded properly. Please convert file to UTF-8 encoding and then read.
You can refer to
[Reading file in different formats](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/util/TextFileSuite.scala)

```
context.hadoopFile[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](location).map(
    pair => new String(pair._2.getBytes, 0, pair._2.getLength, charset)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Default mode is UTF-8. You don't need to specify format explicitly for UTF-8. If it's a non UTF-8 then it depends if you need to read those unsupported characters or not