# Spark Java Reading the file as binary in order to keep encoding

Tags: java, apache-spark, lambda, encoding, special-characters

In spark, i am trying to read a file, when i do that with `javaSparkContext.textFile(localFilePath, 0)`  it is replacing the special characters to UTF-8, in order to avoid that as the solution(Given in the comment) i have tried the below approach

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Object> pairsRDD = 
    javaSparkContext.binaryFiles(localFilePath, 0)
   .mapValues(content -> new String(content.toArray(), 
   StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));

List<Object> list = pairsRDD.map(x -> x._2).collect();

    List<Row> RowList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Object obj : list) {
        String fileContent = (String)obj;
        String[] indLines = fileContent.split("\n");
        for(String indLine : indLines) {
            Row row = processOrdersData(indLine);
            RowList.add(row);
        }
    }
```

I am wondering if we can optimize the code than looping it individually after splitting ("\n"). I tried java lambda ways to map to list like `Collectors.collectasString` but struct with syntax errors

Stack overflow links followed

[Spark: importing text file in UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921757/spark-importing-text-file-in-utf-8-encoding)

[spark read wholeTextFiles with non UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200978/spark-read-wholetextfiles-with-non-utf-8-encoding)